meta ad library PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
I am running this command on my terminal :
C:\Ad-Library-API-Script-Repository-main\python> py fb_ads_library_api_cli.py -t (token) -f "id,page_id,page_name,ad_creative_bodies,spend,demographic_distribution,bylines,ad_delivery_start_time" -c "CA" -s "climate" --after-date "2024-05-01" save_to_csv file.csv

And I get the following error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Ad-Library-API-Script-Repository-main\python\fb_ads_library_api_cli.py", line 147, in
main()
File "C:\Ad-Library-API-Script-Repository-main\python\fb_ads_library_api_cli.py", line 134, in main
save_to_csv(
File "C:\Ad-Library-API-Script-Repository-main\python\fb_ads_library_api_operators.py", line 96, in save_to_csv
with open(output_file, "w") as csvfile:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.

Does anyone have a solution ? i'm not sure I understand how the Permission system works in the Graph Api.
I have tried adding "encoding="utf-8" in the fb_ads_library_api_operators file to fix the encoding issue, but it didn't work (i am able to get one dataset then i get the same error all over again)

Please include a minimal reproducible example.  Is it trying to save file.csv to the same directory as your script?   Do you have RW permissions on it?

"i'm not sure I understand how the Permission system works in the Graph Api." PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. has nothing to do with the Graph API, that is a python error relating to the file system operation it tries to perform on your system.

Yes it is trying to save file.csv to the same directory as the script. the script i'm using is a script i downloaded on my computer from here https://github.com/facebookresearch/Ad-Library-API-Script-Repository?fbclid=IwZXh0bgNhZW0CMTAAAR1XC9koATBcP4IZnhumGGn34ANg_B4_EBJ9ZsWGioiTeS2CZ4ZqVeilkno_aem_AYYw2CxmvDsiX8fy_q8G1c-ThG5icx5j2kkQOGhtFz_VTh70w7Y8gTLvqnEfuOGV2B8Kd4YxaU7EqH3KQU3RPZ2Q
